# Why SQL Expect Parameter to be Integer and mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I got 2 warnings.

**First :**

`mysqli_connect() expects parameter 5 to be integer, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\config\koneksi.php on line 11`

My line 11 is

```
$koneksi = mysqli_connect($server, $id_user, $nama, $username, $password, $level);
```

**Second :**

`mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\config\koneksi.php on line 12`

My line 12 is

```
$selected = mysqli_select_db($koneksi, $database) or die("Couldn't open database $database");
```

**Full Code**

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$id_user = "";
$nama = "";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$level = "";
$database = "penjualan";

$koneksi = mysqli_connect($server, $id_user, $nama, $username, $password, $level);
$selected = mysqli_select_db($koneksi, $database) or die("Couldn't open database $database");
?>
```

Im using PHP 7. Thanks for any help.

**Additional Info**

my check_login.php file that connected to the connection.php

```
<?php
include "../config/koneksi.php";
function antiinjection($data){
  $filter_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string(stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES))));
  return $filter_sql;
}

$id_user    = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['id_user']);
$nama       = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['nama']);
$username   = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['username']);
$password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['password']);
$level      = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['level']);

$login = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user='$id_user' AND nama='$nama' AND username='$username' AND password='$password' AND blokir='N'");
$ketemu = mysqli_num_rows($login);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);

if ($ketemu > 0){
  session_start();
  session_register("id_user");
  session_register("namauser");
  session_register("passuser");
  session_register("leveluser");

 $_SESSION[id_auser]     = $r[id_name];
 $_SESSION[namauser]     = $r[username];
 $_SESSION[passuser]     = $r[password];
 $_SESSION[leveluser]    = $r[level];

 header('location:media.php?module=home');
}
else{
 echo "<link href=style.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css>";
 echo "<center>LOGIN GAGAL!<br> 
     Username atau Password Anda tidak benar<br>
     Atau account Anda sedang diblokir<br>";
 echo "<a href=index.php><b>ULANGI LAGI</b></a></center>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the wrong parameters.

this is correct way how the parameters should be passed.

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```

- host Optional. Specifies a host name or an IP address
- username Optional. Specifies the MySQL username
- password Optional. Specifies the MySQL password
- dbname   Optional. Specifies the default database to be used
- port Optional. Specifies the port number to attempt to connect to the MySQLserver
- socket   Optional. Specifies the socket or named pipe to be used

so in your case i think it should be

```
mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
```

Comment: It makes Undefined Index

Comment: in which line ?

Comment: Additional Info Code, line 8,9,12